# Best way to delete all rows in a table using NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, linq-to-nhibernate

To keep my integration tests independent I remove all old data and insert new test data before each test. Is there a better way of doing this than simply querying for all entities and deleting them one by one?

I have considered writing a stored proc that runs "delete from *tablename*;" for each table that is to be cleared. That ought to quite a bit faster, but it would be nice to do it without doing SQL queries or calling SPs via NH.

I'm using vanilla NHibernate and Linq to NHibernate. I beleive Castle Active Record has something like Foo.DeleteAll(), but I don't want to use Active Record for this project.

Any ideas?

Thanks /Erik

**UPDATE:**

Since this question was asked and answered, progress has been made by the NHibernate team. As Ayende explains in [this blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/28/nhibernate-ndash-executable-dml.aspx), you can now execute DML queries directly, without NHibernate having to fetch any entities.

To delete all Foo objects you could do like this:

```
using (ISession session = ...)
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.CreateQuery("delete Foo f").ExecuteUpdate();

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

This query would generate the following SQL:

```
delete from Foo
```

which aught to be significantly faster than fetching the entities first and then deleting them. Be careful though, since queries like these do not affect the level 1 cache.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server it is MUCH more efficient to execute `TRUNCATE TABLE foo;` as that is a minimally logged operation. Executing `DELETE FROM foo;` logs all the deletes for recovery purposes; on large tables this requires significant disk/time.

Comment: TRUNCATE TABLE is almost never available when there are foreign keys involved.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the TearDown of my UnitTests, I mostly do this:

```
using( ISession s = ... )
{
   s.Delete ("from Object o");
   s.Flush();
}
```

This should delete all entities.
If you want to delete all instances of one specific entity, you can do this:

```
using( ISession s = .... )
{
    s.Delete ("from MyEntityName e");
    s.Flush();
}
```

Offcourse, there's a drawback with this method, and that is that NHibernate will first fetch the entities before deleting them.

Comment: Oh, I had totally missed that you can pass a query to session.Delete(). Thanks!

Comment: BTW: It's deadly slow on large tables

Comment: INdeed, that's the drawback that I mentionned.

Comment: This is equivalent to `foreach(var o in s.Load("from Object o")) s.Delete(o);` which is slooow.

Answer (score 14):

I use Fluent Nhibernate attributes so I modify code a little in order not to hardcore table names

```
private static void CleanUpTable<T>(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    var metadata = sessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(T)) as NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister;
    string table = metadata.TableName;

    using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
    {
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            string deleteAll = string.Format("DELETE FROM \"{0}\"", table);
            session.CreateSQLQuery(deleteAll).ExecuteUpdate();

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

usage

```
CleanUpTable<Person>(sessionFactory);
```

Comment: I've decided against editing this question because “hardcore” really sounds much better than “hardcode”, even though it's the latter that was probably meant.

Answer (score 11):

With NHibernate 5.0 you can now simply do:

```
session.Query<Foo>().Delete();
```

Documentation:

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Delete all entities selected by the specified query. The delete operation is
    //     performed in the database without reading the entities out of it.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   source:
    //     The query matching the entities to delete.
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   TSource:
    //     The type of the elements of source.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The number of deleted entities.
    public static int Delete<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source);
```